# SQL Server 2016 - Error Converting varchar to bigint

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am performing the following operation:

```
UPDATE tblPOParts
SET POStatusID= CAST(5006 as BIGINT)
where POPartsID ='POP-020-50-00563755'
```

*Note: POSTATUSID is foriegn key column and it is of type BIGINT.*

It is throwing this exception:

> as Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
>   Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

**Although, IMO, it didn't require type casting but still after type casting I am getting same message unable to convert datatype varchar to BIGINT**

What could be the reason? If the foreign key constraint was causing the problem, then it would throw a different exception.

Comment: Logical question what is the datatype of this field `POStatusID` the error is telling you what is wrong.

Comment: it is BIGINT i already stated in the question

Comment: Is the POPartsID field bigint?

Comment: What's the type of POPartsID column?

Comment: The error talks about VARCHAR conversion and the only VARCHAR here is in the WHERE condition

Comment: @YogeshJoshi Try it `Update tblPOParts
SET POStatusID= CONVERT(bigint,'5006')
where POPartsID ='POP-020-50-00563755'`

Comment: Can you create a example on http://sqlfiddle.com/ and add a link to it to the question

Comment: Your CAST is fine. I think your WHERE Condition column is expecting a numeric data type, and you are passing in a text type. The error refers to converting a varchar to a bigint, and the only place you can possibly be doing that in this code is in the WHERE clause.

Comment: look for Trigger or computed column.

Comment: Yeah That was the problem with where clause. Closing this question as It doesn't make technical sense.